# Could be possible to enable the sort icons of pivottablejs in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, pivottable.js

I am using **pivottablejs** (pip install [pivottablejs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pivottablejs)) in my Jupyter Notebook and it's great tool, but looking to sort the pivot table and didn't find a way on Jupyter Notebook.
The picture shows the icons pointed by the red arrow.
[image]

My environment was based on Anaconda and pivottables coming in that environment: pivottablejs: 2.7.0-py36_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the `pivottablejs` module (version 0.8.0, released 12 days ago) supports PivotTable.js 2.14.0, and the UI you're looking at was part of PivotTable.js 2.11.0 so if you update the `pivottablejs` module you should be good :)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! your clarification allow me to correct my environment and fix the issue.